# Setting value of date field is not sticking

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to enter the Date of Birth on this page ... https://ccpcares.magellanrx.com/member/registration/

Using this code inside of a NightwatchJS test ...

```
this.api.execute(function () {
    return document.getElementById("reg_dob_val").value = "01/01/1901"
}, [], function (result) {
    console.log("result", result)
})
```

I can see the value is set but as soon as I click or tab out of the field the value disappears.  How can I get the value to "stick"?

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the website to load but you can try use the following after you entered the value

```
browser.keys([browser.Keys.ENTER]);
```

There are fields which require an 'enter' to be pressed in order to stick or a 'save button' to be clicked